# Rails association don't work with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, model-associations

I have a problem with my association in ruby on rails. 
I have the association :

```
class Play < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :program_plays
  has_many :programs, through: :program_plays
end

class ProgramPlay < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :play
end

class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :program_plays
  has_many :plays, through: :program_plays
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plays
end
```

When i create a **Program** i want to associate one or several **Play**. The **Play** are create beforehand. The **Play** have got many attributes whose **:title** and **:id** of course.

The program_controller :

```
class Admin::ProgramsController < Admin::AdminController

  def index
    @programs = Program.all
  end

  def new
    @program = Program.new
    @program.plays.build
  end

  def create
    @program = Program.new(program_params)

    if @program.save
      redirect_to admin_programs_path, notice: ''
    else
    end
  end

  private

  def set_program
    @program = Program.find(params[:id])
  end

  def program_params
    params.require(:program).permit(:start_date, plays_attributes: [:title])
  end
end
```

The form of **Program** (with the simple_form gem) :

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @program] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

      <%= f.association :plays %>

      <%= f.input :start_date, as: :datetime, minute_step: 15, label: 'Heure' %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Poster', class: 'button red-full' %>

<% end %>
```

Now when i want to display the **Program** in my index, i also want to display the **title** of associated **Play**. But when i write :

```
program.plays.title
```

an error tell me that title is not a method of program... Why ? I don't understand. The association is real because when i puts in the rails console :

```
program.plays.to_a
```

i have :

```
 Play Load (5.4ms)  SELECT "plays".* FROM "plays" INNER JOIN "program_plays" ON "plays"."id" = "program_plays"."play_id" WHERE "program_plays"."program_id" = $1  [["program_id", 21]]
=> []
```

Can you see the problem ? I look for it for a longtime ago... I am desperate...

**UPDATE :**

In the rails console when i do `program.plays.first.title` :

```
  Play Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "plays".* FROM "plays" INNER JOIN "program_plays" ON "plays"."id" = "program_plays"."play_id" WHERE "program_plays"."program_id" = $1 ORDER BY "plays"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["program_id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

When i do :

```
program.plays.each do |play|
  play.title
end
```

The result is :

```
  Play Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "plays".* FROM "plays" INNER JOIN "program_plays" ON "plays"."id" = "program_plays"."play_id" WHERE "program_plays"."program_id" = $1  [["program_id", 22]]
=> []
```

Here we can see that *title* is empty...

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
  create_table "plays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "program_plays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "program_id"
    t.bigint "play_id"
    t.index ["play_id"], name: "index_program_plays_on_play_id"
    t.index ["program_id"], name: "index_program_plays_on_program_id"
  end

  create_table "programs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_date"
  end
```

Maybe the problem is here...

**UPDATE 3 :**

```
> program = Program.new
=> #<Program:0x00000000068ce8e8 id: nil, start_date: nil>
[15] pry(main)> program.id = 1
    => 1
    > program.plays.build(Play.find_by(id: 10))
  Play Load (6.2ms)  SELECT  "plays".* FROM "plays" WHERE "plays"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
from /home/coeurcoeur/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:28:in `assign_attributes'
> program.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `.permit(play_ids: [])` to your `program_params` whitelist. Otherwise the associations won't be created.

Comment: And what i put in play_ids: [...] ? the problem seemed to be that my association create a new play and not bound my **Program** with an existing **Play**...

Comment: You don't put anything in, it just makes sure the `:play_ids` parameter is whitelisted as an Array. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Sorry it's don't work. It's maybe i couldn't use build attributes because my **Play** is already create. But what i can write in create to associate my **Play** ?

Answer (score 0):

The associations looks good. the problem that you have is that you are calling `program.plays.title` but have in mind that program.plays will have a collection of plays and not just one so you can't call directly the title there.

it depends on what you are trying to do, for example if you want the title of the first play, you can do something like `program.plays.first.title`

or if you want to print all the plays title you can do something like

```
program.plays.each do |play|
  play.title
end
```

and I am assuming program is filled with an existing program in your code

Another problem that you have is that you are not permitting the program_id on the controller so when you create the plays, the attribute program_id that has the association isn't saved because isn't permitted, so just add program_id on your params method like this

```
def program_params
  params.require(:program).permit(:start_date, plays_attributes: [:title, :program_id]) 
end
```

Comment: `program.plays.title` make an error undefined method *title* and the other display puts nothing... *Title* seems empty. maybe it's the `f.association` from simple_form, no ?

Comment: Can you add to the question the view and the error output complete

Comment: Ok don't worry we are here to help, edited the end of the answer

Comment: I am damn is not possible... every solution you give to me failed... `program.plays.first.title` return again `undefined method 'title'` and the other display work (no error) but nothing appear...

Comment: But you have to create new data, the old one still doesn't have the attribute populated. And of course you need to validate it when a program doesn't have plays associated if this could happen in your app

Comment: Of course. I create a new **Program** and also a new **Play** but it's the same problem. I update my post with the shema.rb of the concerned table

Comment: well the problem is not about configuration, everything is looking good, the problem here is that the association isn't saved, can you add the request console on the question too? but a complete one, the request when you try to save the plays for a program

Comment: First post edited. Tell me if the cmd are not good. I would do it again.

Comment: with that last update, you can change it to 
program.plays.build(Play.find_by(id: 10)) and then
program.save

Comment: ok, that is a problem with the way it's created, but if you do something like program.plays.build(title: "some title") it have to work. it will create a new play and it will work, the way you associate a created one will change when you do it on your application flow

Comment: Yes `program.plays.build(title: "some title")` work very well... But it's create a new play and no associate whit an existing play... How i can change the way to create in my simple_form directly or in my controller ?

Comment: The problem is i use build attributes in my controller because my **Play** is already create so i must write something in my create of my controller but i don't now what...

Comment: In that case, just build the association and not try directly with the play because is already created. program.program_plays.build(play_id: 10)